# Find all almost lower bounds and almost upper bounds of $\{\frac 1n: n\in \Bbb N\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> A number $x$ is called an **almost upper bound** for $A$ if there are only finitely many numbers $y$ in $A$ with $y\ge x$. An **almost lower bound** is defined similarly.
>
> (a) Find all almost lower bounds and almost upper bounds of the set
>   $A=\{\frac 1n: n\in \Bbb N\}$
>
> (Source: Problem 18 in chapter 8 of Spivak's Calculus)

My answer: Denote **almost upper bound for A** by $Al.sup(A)$ and similarly with **almost lower bound** by $Al.inf(A)$. The answer is: $x=Al.sup(A)=1$ since it is the ONLY number that has a finite $y$ $\in$ A (only one value: 1). $Al.inf(A)=1$ for the same reason.

Spivak's answer book: All $\alpha$ $\gt$ $0$ for $Al.sup(A)$ and all $\alpha$ $\le$ $0$ for $Al.inf(A)$

**My question: What is wrong with my answer? I do not understand anything at all. What exactly again is the $Al.sup(A)$ and $Al.inf(A)$ Spivak wants to talk about?**

I thank you very much for having helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a concrete example, consider $\beta = 0.21 > 0$. Notice that $\beta$ is an almost upper bound for $A$ because there are only finitely many elements in $A$ that are greater than or equal to $\beta = 0.21$. Indeed, the only four elements of $A$ that prevent $\beta$ from being a true upper bound for $A$ are:

- $\frac{1}{1} = 1 \geq 0.21$
- $\frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \geq 0.21$
- $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline 3 \geq 0.21$
- $\frac{1}{4} = 0.25 \geq 0.21$

All other elements of $A$ are smaller than $0.21$.

Comment: If I take $\alpha$ = $5$, there will be no $y$ $\in$ A such that $\alpha$ is the almost upper bound for A.

Comment: An equivalent definition is this: $\alpha$ is an almost upper bound for $A$ iff the set $S = \{y \in A \mid y \geq \alpha\}$ has finite size. For $\alpha = 5$, we have $S = \{\}$, and $|S| = 0$ is certainly a finite number. So $\alpha = 5$ is indeed an almost upper bound. Every upper bound for $A$ is also an almost upper bound for $A$.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I UNDERSTAND NOW. *CLAP CLAP* YOU ARE SO INTELLIGENT, AND SO IS MR.SPIVAK.

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and verify Spivak's answer. Let $\alpha >0$. How many element of the form $1/n$ satisfy $1/n > \alpha $? The answer is only finitely many and thus $\alpha $ is an almost upper bound. Now take any $\alpha \le 0$. How many elements of the form $1/n$ satisfy $1/n>\alpha $? The answer is all of them, so not just finitely many and thus $\alpha $ is not an almost upper bound. This shows that $\alpha $ is an almost upper bound if, and only if, $\alpha >0$. You can argue similarly for the answer to the almost lower bound.

Comment: No, $\frac 1n$ $\lt$ $\alpha$, by Archimedian property. As for the rest, since n is not bounded above by Archimedian property, there is INFINITELY MANY $\frac 1n$ (1,1/2,1/3,.....) that satisfy $\frac 1n$ $\gt$ $\alpha$

Comment: Imagine that $\alpha = 1/2$ and now think again about what you just said.